# CompletionProcessor Eclipse Plugin - Replace actual value in the editor

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I have a simple question, but I couldn't solve it by myself.

I made a Eclipse Plugin, It's just an editor which has a CompletionProcessor (intelisense assitant). This assistant retrieve a set of phrases take into account a dictionary.

The thing is if i write "**word example**" in the editor and the assistant proposes "**Word as an Example**" I would like to **replace** my actual value for the value that get from my assistant.

To summarize actually when I pick that option , in my editor I get something like the following:

```
"word example Word as an Example"
```

And I would like to get just:

```
"Word as an Example"
```

Any idea?

The classes I have been using are the following:

```
org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.CompletionProposal;
org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.ICompletionProposal;
org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.IContentAssistProcessor;
org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.IContextInformation;
org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.IContextInformationValidator;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm gonna answer my own question :).

To solve this you have to use the following constructor of Completion Proposal:

http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/text/contentassist/CompletionProposal.html#CompletionProposal(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image,%20java.lang.String,%20org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.IContextInformation,%20java.lang.String)

As you can see two of its arguments are replacementOffset and replacementLength, these are the index to start replacement and the length itself.